# Mongoose elemMatch returns an empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently building a web application and I have stumbled upon a problem I wasn't able to solve for the past 12 hours.

I am working on a basic get method where I am trying to retrieve certain work positions (i.e. cashier, clerk) that an employee is working as (the client-side works perfectly).

The mongoose model for WorkPosition is such (models/work-position.js):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('./user');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var schema = new Schema ({
    workplace : {type: String, required: true},
    type : {type: String, required: true},
    status : {type: String, required: true},
    color : {type: String, required: true},
    employees: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'}]
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('WorkPosition', schema);
```

My get method (routes/work-position.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var User = require('../models/user');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var WorkPosition = require('../models/work-position');

router.get('/:userId', function(req, res, next) {
    const userId = req.params.userId;
    WorkPosition.find({employees: {$elemMatch : {$eq: userId}}})
        .exec(function(err, workPositions) {
            if(err) {
                return res.status(500).json({
                    title: 'an error has occurred',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            console.log(userId);
            console.log(workPositions);
            res.status(200).json({
                message: 'Success',
                obj: workPositions
            });
        });
});
```

The problem arises when I try to use the $elemMatch method. The code above, when the WorkPosition.find line is changed to

```
WorkPosition.find()
```

without any conditions (

```
{employees: {$elemMatch : {$eq: userId}}}
```

) inside, I am successfully able to retrieve the WorkPosition document that I desire.

However, I want to only retrieve the WorkPosition documents where the 'employees' field in WorkPosition matches the 'userId' I have received from req.params. Therefore, I searched through the mongodb/mongoose API (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-elemMatch)

where I found the $elemMatch method.

In the mongodb shell, when I do

```
db.workpositions.find({"employees": { $elemMatch : {$eq: "596823efbac11d1978ba2ee9"}}})
```

where "5968...." is the userId, I am successfully able to query the WorkPosition document.

Through this command, I am able to verify that my logic is correct, and using the mongodb native shell command gets me the document I desire.

However, when I try to convert the same logic to the Mongoose API, which is:

```
WorkPosition.find().elemMatch('employees', {$eq : userId})
```

I get an empty array, and adding lines

```
mongoose.set('debug', function (coll, method, query, doc) {
    console.log(coll + " " + method + " " + JSON.stringify(query) + " " + JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```

in /app.js , I am able to see what the mongoose query translates to native mongodb command which is :

```
workpositions find {"employees":{"$elemMatch":{"$eq":"596823efbac11d1978ba2ee9"}}} {"fields":{}}
```

. The collection (workpositions), method (find), array to seek (employees) and everything is correctly translated to native mongodb command EXCEPT

```
"$eq"
```

. The only difference between the shell command that successfully works and the mongoose command in my code is the additional quotation marks around '$eq'.

shell:

```
db.workpositions.find({"employees": { $elemMatch : {$eq: "596823efbac11d1978ba2ee9"}}})
```

mongoose:

```
db.workpositions.find({"employees": { $elemMatch : {"$eq": "596823efbac11d1978ba2ee9"}}})
```

I cannot seem to find a way to get rid of these extra quotation marks (which I believe is the cause of the problem). I tried using the native command with mongoose like :

```
mongoose.connection.db.workpositions.find(.....)
```

but this also results in an error.

What is the proper way to use elemMatch through mongoose? Can anyone enlighten me how to use it? I tried every way I could think of, and I cannot seem to get past this problem.

I am thinking of changing the WorkPosition.employees field so that it holds actual Users (not only userIds), and I can parse through with additional information that exactly matches the Mongoose elemMatch API. However, I believe this will waste a HUGE amount of database space because each WorkPosition has to carry an array of Users.

To have the correct relationship between Users and WorkPositions, the elemMatch is a requirement in my project. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: As your employees field is just an array of ids, could you not just use: WorkPosition.find({ employees: userId })

Comment: Quoting your question *"In the mongodb shell, when I do `db.workpositions.find({"employees": { $elemMatch : {$eq: "596823efbac11d1978ba2ee9"}}})` I am successful (sic)"*. So there's your problem. If you can run that query in the "shell" then the content of `"employees"` is actually "strings" and **not** `ObjectId` values, of which your schema is expecting. Seems your existing data has problems and you need to fix those entries to be `ObjectId` values instead. The shell query should have failed because you did not cast the value. Mongoose is trying to cast the value.

Comment: For future reference, always add `mongoose.set('debug',true)` to your program. That logs all queries issued from your mongoose models, and then you should be able to see clear differences like the one just illustrated.

Comment: First off, thank you @NeilLunn for indicating the small but major mistake I have made. There was an inconsistency between my document and schema (String is not an ObjectId!). elemMatch successfully returns what I want!

Comment: @SteveHolgado I was worried that find({employees: userId}) would not work if the field was an array, but I have tried it and that successfully works as well.

Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Please use **mongoose.Types.ObjectId** around the $eq array operator when comparing mongodb ObjectIds, then you can retrieve the first document that matches the condition with $elemMatch operator.

> $elemMatch:{$eq:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}